# how to conditionally redirect to another omniscript?

Tags: vlocity, omniscript

Assume I have omniscripts a,b and c. They are all contain a single step each.
I'd like to create a user experience where starting at omniscript a, depending on a selection made the user would be redirected to omniscript b or omniscript c seamlessly. Same effect as a Salesforce flow subflow being launched based on a radio button input for example.  Using conditionally rendered steps all within a single omniscript is not feasible for this use case.

Is this seamless redirect to other omniscripts possible, and if so - how? So far my use of navigation action results in new tabs opening or a complete page refresh which is sub-optimal. Any tips most appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the conditional (child) OS outside of a step. The child OS should be marked as "reusable". In the example screenshot, the child OS will be called if the condition sets to true.

[image: Simple example.]